# On Mac OSX, is there a means by which I can have git without XCode?

Tags: git, xcode

...or is that a license violation or something? Our network is dog slow and XCode is bloody huge and we don't even use it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to install Hombrew from https://brew.sh/ .  When that finishes up, run 'brew install git'.

The official Git maintainers have several other methods of installing it listed at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git .  They have an installer at http://git-scm.com/download/mac .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just install a precompiled git binary, like the one you can download from the official Git site:
https://git-scm.com/download/mac

I believe open source package managers for Mac, such as Homebrew and MacPorts, often have ways to install precompiled binary packages as well. But sometimes some of the dependencies won't have a precompiled binary packages, so you'll end up needing a compiler, which basically means you'll need to install the Xcode dev tools at that point.